# How to get list of branches "merged" to git tag

Tags: git, version-control, git-tag

We are tagging master with release number. I want to get list of branches that were merged to master branch before a specific release tag was created.

I could do it by hand calling `git tag --contains last_commit_of_each_branch` but I'm lazy.

Is there a better way to do it? Or should I just script getting all branches and calling `contains` for last commits in each of those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**, find the branches which were merged into `master` by `git branch --merged master`. Assume the branches merged into `master` are `branch1`, `branch2`,…,`branchn`.

**Second**, check if a branch or some branches added tags on the last commit of each branch.

Check if `branchx` added tag on the last commit: `git tag --contains branchx`.

Check if `branchm` and `branchn` added tags on the last commits: `git tag --contains branchm --contains branchn`.

Of cause, you can use script to achieve it and it’s more time saving.

Comment: As far as I know git tag --contains does not take branch name as parameter, only commit hash. Or you meant something else by branchx.

Comment: @Wojtek: `git tag --contains`, `git branch --contains`, etc., take *any valid commit specifier:* a branch name, a tag name, a hash ID, etc., are all valid as long as they can be resolved to a commit hash (via `git rev-parse`). See [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) for all the ways to specify a commit.

Comment: @Wojtek `--contains` can add branch, because the branch name is point to the last commit id.